# Is it possible to statically create a regular expression in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I am ruby programer, and in ruby it is possible to create regexps statically like /myregexp/.

In python, the only way I found was to create it dinamically from a string using re.compile('myregexp').

It is no big deal but I don't like to create static immutable objects using a dinamyc sintax.

Comment: Ruby still has to compile the regex at *some* stage into a `Regexp` object. It's just not explicit in Ruby.

Comment: @nneonneo: True. The main difference is the `syntactic sugar` provided by the `=~` operator, which `Python` (and `Java`) lacks.

Comment: @KenHampson: True. By the way, for emphasis, I think it is better to use `*` instead of using the code notation. That renders as *syntactic sugar* instead of `syntactic sugar`, which seems more natural in English. (Personal preference, really, but that seems to be the way most folks do it around here).

Comment: @nneonneo: Interesting point re: italics vs. highlighting. I'll try switching.

Comment: Thank you all for the quick replies fellas! =) Now let's get back to coding because it is only 1am!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what functions you're using, you don't necessarily have to compile the regex, but it's **not** a built-in operator the way it is in Ruby or Perl. Python Java more closely when it comes to regexes.

The closest it gets to static (although it ultimately will get compiled in the function) is something like this (from the Python doc):

```
>>> import re
>>> m = re.search('(?<=abc)def', 'abcdef')
>>> m.group(0)
'def'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
whatever_re = re.compile(r'whatever')

def function_which_uses_a_re(stuff):
    match = whatever_re.match(stuff)
```

which will do the equivalent of what Ruby does ... compile the re once up front and use it over and over.

Comment: Python uses a regexp cache, so even using it as `re.match(pat, str)` over and over in a loop isn't really that bad.